# Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager:jar is missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, maven-3, aws-secrets-manager

In my pom.xml in  section,I have added following dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.95</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Then in `<dependencies>` section,I am adding following :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Why I am getting compile time error :
Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager:jar is missing.

Comment: Do you use a parent pom? If not, your dependency must contain a version. With Maven 3 you can use the ${project.version} notation. Check more 
[here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance)

Comment: @Aviza That is not true. He/She expects the version to come from the imported bom, which should work _if_ this bom really specifies a version for the desired artifact.

Comment: From its [description](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bom/1.11.95) doesn't seem that secretsmanager is a dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider using the [AWS SDK for Java V2](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2). Amazon Strongly recommends moving away from V1 to V2.

To use AWS Secrets Manager, use these POM dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                 <version>2.17.46</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

and

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
         <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>
         **<version>2.17.46</version>**
   </dependency>
```

For this service, it seems it wants a version for AWS Secrets Manager.

Here you can find all of the [Secret Manager code examples](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/secretsmanager).

Answer (score 0):

Yea secrets manager was released in April 2018. This bom doesn't have secrets manager in it's collection of dependencies